# Get the last refresh date/time of an Excel query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I built a query to read a file into Excel.

```
//Query - Read File:

let 
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(...)),
    ...
    #"Transformed file contents" = ...
in
    #"Transformed file contents"
```

I [set properties of the query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/refresh-an-external-data-connection-in-excel-1524175f-777a-48fc-8fc7-c8514b984440#:%7E:text=Automatically%20refresh%20data%20at%20regular%20intervals&text=external%20data%20range.-,Select%20Data%20%3E%20Queries%20%26%20Connections%20%3E%20Connections%20tab%2C%20right%20click,minutes%20between%20each%20refresh%20operation.) to refresh it every 1 minute and it seems to be working.

To give our users (and me) confidence that the refresh is working properly, I'd like to capture the date/time of the refresh ***of this query***.

I know how to create a separate query which captures the date/time of that separate query.  However, this separate query could succeed but the query reading the file could fail.

**Approach 1 - Not Desired**

```
//Query - Get Date/Time:

let #"Last Refresh Date" = DateTime.LocalNow()
```

Using this approach, `Query - Read File` could fail and `Query - Get Date/Time` could succeed.

**Approach 2 - Desired**

```
//Query - Read File2:

Let 
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(...)),
    ...
    #"Transformed file contents" = ...,
    #"Last Refresh Date" = DateTime.LocalNow()
in
    #"Transformed file contents"
```

The query `Query - Read File2` works, but I don't know how to access the value of `#"Last Refresh Date` in an Excel worksheet.

I could add a column to `Query - Read File` which is the current date/time per https://stackoverflow.com/a/65777778/11262633.  I'd rather not incur the overhead of repeated data.

Is there a different way to bring into an Excel worksheet the refresh date/time of `Query - Read File` in either example above?

Comment: why dont you just append the refresh date to the bottom of your query to return to excel?

Comment: @horseyride, Are you saying I'd add a new column to ```Query - Read File``` with the current date/time?  Yes, I could do that, but it has the overhead of adding this data to every row in the query.  I then need to select the first row of the query to get the desired date.  Not exactly elegant.

Comment: Add a ROW with the date in a single exiting or new column as the last query step  FinalAppend = Table.Combine({#"PriorStepName",#table({"Column Name"}, {{DateTime.LocalNow()}})})

Comment: @horseyride, yes, adding a row could work.  It's inelegant as really this new row needs to be ignored by other queries.  However I could create another query to filter it out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just in case comments disappear, as they sometimes do, my inelegant solution was

Add a row with the date in a single exiting or new column as the last query step

```
FinalAppend = Table.Combine({#"PriorStepName",#table({"Column Name"}, {{DateTime.LocalNow()}})})
```