# Reading connection Last Refresh date

Tags: vba, excel-2019

When I hover over a Power Query connection in Queries and Connection menu, I can see short preview of data, list of columns, date of last refresh, load state, source of data and quick menu with view/edit and remove buttons.

Is there a way to retrieve this date of last refresh? Preferably I'd like to write a funtion that would take name of a query as input and output that date.

I've found DataFeedConnection.RefreshDate property but it does not seem to apply to a power query connection (error 1004)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65777638/how-to-determine-last-refresh-of-power-query-in-source-workbook

Comment: From what I can tell, you can't get this info from a `WorkbookConnection` object representing a Power Query connection.